# Optimal table structure for message system in Laravel 5

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, migration

I'm trying to figure out how to make the most efficient messaging system for users.

My idea is that (very similar to Facebook) when a user sends a message to another user, then it creates a thread where all messages send between the users are displayed. It is important that new messages are flagged as unread for the recipient.

I want to leverage Laravels relations.

If I create a pivot table that contains the recipient id and sender id, how can I get Laravel to differentiate the 2 users using Laravels relations, so that I can easily get a list of threads where the user is involved, whether he's just the recipient, sender or both.

A thread does not need a title/subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
class User extends Model {
    public function threads() { return $this->belongsToMany(Thread::class)->withPivot('last_read_message_id'); }
}

class Thread extends Model {
    public function users() { return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withPivot('last_read_message_id'); }
    public function messages() { return $this->hasMany(ThreadMessage::class); }
}

class ThreadMessage extends Model {
    public function thread() { return $this->belongsTo(Thread::class); }
    public function author() { return $this->belongsTo(User::class); }
}

// List of threads where a user is involved:
Auth::user()->threads;
```

With this design, you can also handle groups of discussion, which is quite nice.